# CKEditor - display chinese (unicode) characters

Tags: php, unicode, ckeditor

I just set up CKEditor for my project where I am pulling content from a textfile and display it via CKEditor on the webpage. The user can edit around and save the modifications which then are being written back into the textfile, which then again is later used as an email template. This works well for English (Latin) characters, but sadly not for Chinese (Unicode).

what I tried so far:
- updated CKEditor settings to `config.entities = false;`
- made sure the textfile is in unicode
- browsers (Chrome) runs on unicode

Would appreciate if someone could help, respectively let me know if there is a better way to go about this (use SQL instead of textfiles, etc)...

Thanks!